# Efficient way to remove all non-alphanumeric characters from large text

Tags: go

I need to process volumes of text and one of the steps is to remove all non-alphanumeric characters. I'm trying to find an efficient way to do it.

So far I have two functions:

```
func stripMap(str, chr string) string {
    return strings.Map(func(r rune) rune {
        if strings.IndexRune(chr, r) < 0 {
            return r
        }
        return -1
    }, str)
}
```

Here I actually have to feed a string of all non-alpha characters.

And plain old regex

```
func stripRegex(in string) string {
    reg, _ := regexp.Compile("[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]+")
    return reg.ReplaceAllString(in, "")
}
```

The regex one seems to be much slower

```
BenchmarkStripMap-8        30000         37907 ns/op        8192 B/op          2 allocs/op

BenchmarkStripRegex-8          10000        131449 ns/op       57552 B/op         35 allocs/op
```

Looking for suggestions. Any other better way to do it? Improve the above?

Comment: Regex is usually slower, so no surprise there. What is your actual question?

Comment: If this has to be done synchronously, there's no really any trick I am aware of to make it faster than just going through each character and replacing it if needed.

Comment: @Flimzy Question is in the title and at the bottom of the post. Just looking for an fast way to do it

Comment: Asking for faster ways to write code isn't on-topic here. Maybe [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) can do this.

Comment: @matiit Confirmation that nothing else can be done is good too

Comment: @Flimzy: "Maybe Code Review can do this." Not likely.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because the surviving runes are less than [utf8.RuneSelf](https://godoc.org/unicode/utf8#RuneSelf), this problem can be solved by operating on bytes.  If any byte is not in `[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]`, then the byte is part of a rune to be removed.

```
func strip(s string) string {
    var result strings.Builder
    for i := 0; i < len(s); i++ {
        b := s[i]
        if ('a' <= b && b <= 'z') ||
            ('A' <= b && b <= 'Z') ||
            ('0' <= b && b <= '9') ||
            b == ' ' {
            result.WriteByte(b)
        }
    }
    return result.String()
}
```

A variation on this function is to preallocate the result by calling result.Grow:

```
func strip(s string) string {
    var result strings.Builder
    result.Grow(len(s))
    ...
```

This ensures that the function makes one memory allocation, but that memory allocation may be significantly larger than needed if the ratio of surviving runes to source runes is low.

The `strip` function in this answer is written to work with `string` argument and result types because those are the types used in the question.

If the application is working a `[]byte` source text and that source text can be modified, then it will be more efficient to update the `[]byte` in place. To do this, copy the surviving bytes to the beginning of the slice and reslice when done. This avoids memory allocations and overhead in strings.Builder. This variation is similar to one in peterSO's answer to this question.

```
func strip(s []byte) []byte {
    n := 0
    for _, b := range s {
        if ('a' <= b && b <= 'z') ||
            ('A' <= b && b <= 'Z') ||
            ('0' <= b && b <= '9') ||
            b == ' ' {
            s[n] = b
            n++
        }
    }
    return s[:n]
}
```

Depending on actual data used, one of the approaches in this answer may be faster than the approaches in the question.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. The string version runs 3 times faster than map. []byte version is even faster ...

Answer (score 6):

> Efficient way to remove all non-alphanumeric characters from large text.

---

In Go, "Efficient way" means that we run Go `testing` package benchmarks.

Your descripion of large text is vague. Let's assume that it began as text from a file or other `byte` slice.

You could have overhead for `string([]byte)`, several `make([]byte)`, and `string([]byte)`.

You can use `strings.Builder` to reduce the overhead to `string([]byte)` and several `make([]byte)`.

You can reduce that even further to `string([]byte)` by starting with a `clean([]byte) string` function.

For example,

```
func clean(s []byte) string {
    j := 0
    for _, b := range s {
        if ('a' <= b && b <= 'z') ||
            ('A' <= b && b <= 'Z') ||
            ('0' <= b && b <= '9') ||
            b == ' ' {
            s[j] = b
            j++
        }
    }
    return string(s[:j])
}
```

For a large text, the complete works of Shakespeare as a `[]byte`,

```
$ go fmt && go test strip_test.go -bench=. -benchmem
BenchmarkSendeckyMap-8       20     65988121 ns/op    11730958 B/op      2 allocs/op
BenchmarkSendeckyRegex-8      5    242834302 ns/op    40013144 B/op    130 allocs/op
BenchmarkThunder-8          100     21791532 ns/op    34682926 B/op     43 allocs/op
BenchmarkPeterSO-8          100     16172591 ns/op     5283840 B/op      1 allocs/op
$
```

`strip_test.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
    "testing"
)

func stripMap(str, chr string) string {
    return strings.Map(func(r rune) rune {
        if strings.IndexRune(chr, r) >= 0 {
            return r
        }
        return -1
    }, str)
}

var alphanum = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789 "

func BenchmarkSendeckyMap(b *testing.B) {
    for N := 0; N < b.N; N++ {
        b.StopTimer()
        bytShakespeare := []byte(strShakespeare)
        b.StartTimer()
        strShakespeare = string(bytShakespeare)
        stripMap(strShakespeare, alphanum)
    }
}

func stripRegex(in string) string {
    reg, _ := regexp.Compile("[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]+")
    return reg.ReplaceAllString(in, "")
}

func BenchmarkSendeckyRegex(b *testing.B) {
    for N := 0; N < b.N; N++ {
        b.StopTimer()
        bytShakespeare := []byte(strShakespeare)
        b.StartTimer()
        strShakespeare = string(bytShakespeare)
        stripRegex(strShakespeare)
    }
}

func strip(s string) string {
    var result strings.Builder
    for i := 0; i < len(s); i++ {
        b := s[i]
        if ('a' <= b && b <= 'z') ||
            ('A' <= b && b <= 'Z') ||
            ('0' <= b && b <= '9') ||
            b == ' ' {
            result.WriteByte(b)
        }
    }
    return result.String()
}

func BenchmarkThunder(b *testing.B) {
    for N := 0; N < b.N; N++ {
        b.StopTimer()
        bytShakespeare := []byte(strShakespeare)
        b.StartTimer()
        strShakespeare = string(bytShakespeare)
        strip(strShakespeare)
    }
}

func clean(s []byte) string {
    j := 0
    for _, b := range s {
        if ('a' <= b && b <= 'z') ||
            ('A' <= b && b <= 'Z') ||
            ('0' <= b && b <= '9') ||
            b == ' ' {
            s[j] = b
            j++
        }
    }
    return string(s[:j])
}

func BenchmarkPeterSO(b *testing.B) {
    for N := 0; N < b.N; N++ {
        b.StopTimer()
        bytShakespeare := []byte(strShakespeare)
        b.StartTimer()
        clean(bytShakespeare)
    }
}

var strShakespeare = func() string {
    // The Complete Works of William Shakespeare by William Shakespeare
    // http://www.gutenberg.org/files/100/100-0.txt
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(`/home/peter/shakespeare.100-0.txt`)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return string(data)
}()
```

Comment: Even if you pass string as an argument to `clean` and then cast it to []byte right after, it is still faster than `strip`. Brilliant. Thanks